# How to select the range of text from UIVIew in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiview

am populating the pdf in custom UIVIew. Now i wish to enable selection of text from screen. If it is a Webview , single Tap gives me a selection range along with Edit Menu automatically ( native iOS behaviour). how to do that programmatically ?  Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you provide more info? How do you present the text? Its almost impossible to anwser without proper info.

Comment: Thanks for your comment .. i mention below the code of Draw Rect..

Answer (score 0):

This is my drawRect code of UIVIew subclass. Am passing the "_page" pdf page from ViewController.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat frameWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat frameHeight = self.frame.size.height;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, frameHeight);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(_page,
                                          kCGPDFBleedBox);
    CGFloat pageWidth = pageRect.size.width;
    CGFloat pageHeight = pageRect.size.height;
    CGFloat scaleRatio = 1;

    if (pageWidth < pageHeight) {
        scaleRatio = frameHeight / pageHeight;
    } else {
        scaleRatio = frameWidth / pageWidth;
    }

    CGFloat xOffset = (frameWidth - pageWidth
                       * scaleRatio) / 2;
    CGFloat yOffset = (frameHeight - pageHeight
                       * scaleRatio) / 2;

    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform =
    CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(
                                 _page, kCGPDFMediaBox,
                                 CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, pageWidth,
                                            pageHeight), 0, true);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformScale(
                                                       pdfTransform, scaleRatio, scaleRatio));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _page);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);




}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `UIView`, you might want to look into using Quartz 2D's 
[CGPDFDocumentRef](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq%5Fpdf/dq%5Fpdf.html) and parsing a `[CGPDFDictionary][2]` for [strings of interest](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Quartz-dev/2008/Jul/msg00019.html).

Once your know which PDF dictionary elements contain your text and where they are located, you might be able to highlight that text with [other Quartz 2D routines](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17024).

Another option might be to convert your PDF document to RTF or HTML formats, either of which would probably be easier to parse and edit to add highlighting.

**UPD:**

Complete tutorial on this topic can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html).

Comment: am currently using CGPDFDocumentRef object for my pdf. how to display that ? which UI element i have to use...  current scenario is every page are generated inside UIVIew and those are become a subview of scrollview.. So that i achieved the readability.      if i extracted that string how do i display that ?  Thanks for your reply..

Comment: I recommend you to read through [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) posted by apple. It is a quite big topic so if you invest some time you'll come up with a powerful pdf instrument which is extremely flexible and which will most likely meet your requests.

Comment: Thank you for your link @Maxim.... apart from this , if there any other brief tutorial available means plz let me know.. once again thank you..

Comment: @RathnaKumaran Personally I would be happy if there was a tutorial on this. I've searched for about 30 minutes around the web and only tutorials I managed to find were the ones with the most basic stuff such as displaying the PDF. Text selection seems to be pretty unpopular thing and most tutorials avoid it becuase their main audience wouldn't need it. To be honest with you at first I was scared as shit of documentation but after about 3 years of iOS programming I realized that sometimes docs are the best thing ever if you want to move beyond mediocratic stuff and create really cool apps.